# Is there a common expression for the 'ulnar border of the palm'?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I would like to describe the action of removing dust/sand from a surface with the **ulnar border of the palm** (see image, highlighted in green), but I cannot find an informal yet precise expression to refer to this body part. In Italian, we informally call this part "il taglio della mano" (literally, the cut of the hand). I was wondering if there is an equally informal and less anatomical expression to refer to this body part in English? Thanks!

[image: ulnar border of hand]

Comment: I don't think we would be (or need to be) that specific. You can get it from the verb. *He swept the sand away with his hand* would conjure the ulnar border action. *Brushed* would be more fingers and palm.

Comment: *blade of the hand* would probably be understood although I can't find many references.

Comment: @TinfoilHat, thank you, that's a very good suggestion. Although "sweeping with one's hand" could also include sweeping with palm or back of the hand? I need it to be specific because the narrator is recalling and replicating an action exactly as she witnessed it.

Comment: @StuartF, interestingly, I found "blade of the hand" only in the context of martial arts (e.g., hand position of knifehand strike) and cheerleading hand formations. Probably too context-dependent for my sentence

Comment: Sweeping with a palm would be inefficient; we would naturally apply the ulnar border. Sweeping with the back of the hand would also be inefficient, and painful; I can't imagine anyone doing that. Are you talking about a police report or something where the precise anatomy matters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"The side of the hand." "The side of one's hand"**

Were you referring to the side with the thumb on it, it would be **"Removing sand from between the thumb and forefinger"**

**Java Lost, a Child Imprisoned: Eighteen Inches on a Mattress** - Jannie Wilbrink • 2011
*With the side of his hand he stripped about half an inch of dirt from off the top and pushed it to one side*

The Angels of Resistance (Hardcover) - David V. Mammina • 2013 *Maxim swatted the blade away with lightning speed and spun around the justice's body to chop the back of his neck with the side of his hand.*

**Part Two Margaret's Life and the Return of the Ghosts** - Tom Marovich 2020. *“Mom, how's Dad doin'?” Tears rolled down his mother's cheeks. “Michael, your dad's getting tired.” With the side of his hand, Michael gently wiped the tears from his mother's cheeks.*

**Coeur D'alene - Linnea Larsson** • 2008 *[He] hit Dave Wilson's wrist with the side of his hand to break the grip Dave had on Celest's arm*

**The Life and Adventures of Trobadora Beatrice As Chronicled** Irmtraud Morgner · 2000 *Pakulat stroked the side of his hand across the table , pushing the bills and coins toward him .*